# What is the difference between ASP and SaaS models?

Tags: saas

I am interested in finding a business model for a software product (iprocurement). However, I got quite confused between ASP (Application Service Provider) and Saas models. What are the differences?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though medium of delivery is the same i.e. internet, ASP takes a packaged-base approach while SaaS takes product approach. ASP provider need not be a manufacturer of the product. He can be a trader or a middleman who takes the responsibility of selling it and customising and implementing it when required. On the other hand, a system based on Saas model had been designed, built, delivered, configured and implemented normally by a single party who has total control of the system.

In case of ASP there can be multiple instances (or implementations) of a software running on a single server, suitable as per customer needs while in case of SaaS, a single software will serve to many clients allowing them to configure the service as per their requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental difference is how software is built and used.  ASP follows traditional development with a twist when it comes to deployment.  It is built on data centric and it is deployed as an application with a centralized host sever.  SaaS is built on service centric and deployed as web services.